# Batch file move to directory structure based on filename

Tags: bash, rename, date

I am writing a script to move files into directories based on the filename. Files have `yyyyddmm-xxxxxxx.jpg` name format. 
The desired directory structure is in the format `2013/01 Jan/31`. I am unable to get `date` to format correctly with a space between month number and month name. When I try to use `+%Y/%m %b` format, I get this error message:

> date: extra operand `%b"'

I tried double and single quotation marks, but to no avail. However, `date +"%Y/%m %b/%d"` works fine in `sh`:

> 2013/10/27 Oct

Also, is there a better way to generate the directory name than using `MOVEDIRSTR` and `MOVEDIR` variables (see script)?

Here's my current script:

```
FLIST=`ls "$IMGDIR" | grep -E '^.*\.jpg$'`

# If there are files to move
if [ -n "${FLIST}" ]; then
    # For each file
    while read -r line; do
        # Parse filename to YYYY/mm Mmm/Dd
        echo $line
        MOVEDIRSTR=`sed -r -e 's:([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}).*:date -d \1-\2-\3 +%Y/%m_%b/%d:' <<< "$line"`
        MOVEDIR=`$MOVEDIRSTR`

        # If a directory does not exist, create it
        [ -d "$ARCHIVEDIR/$MOVEDIR" ] || (mkdir -p "$ARCHIVEDIR/$MOVEDIR")

        # Move file into YYYY/mm Mmm directory
        # mv -f "$IMGDIR/$line" "$ARCHIVEDIR/$MOVEDIR"
    done <<< "$FLIST"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to quote the format to date after the `+` sign.

```
$ date +"%Y/%m %b"
2013/10 Oct
```

Regarding the variables. `$MOVEDIRSTR` seems unecessary.

```
MOVEDIR=$(sed -r -e 's:([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}).*:date -d \1-\2-\3 +%Y/%m_%b/%d:' <<< "$line")
```

Since with `$FLIST` you're parsing out the dates from that directory, I don't see a cleaner way.

#### UPDATE #1

Given the OP's feedback in the comments below, he's using a QNAP device and so likely has a watered down version of these commands provided by BusyBox. If you look at the date command like so: `ls -l /bin/date` it's probably a link to an executable called busybox or something similar. These commands aren't full-featured, hence your problems.

He confirmed this:

> You're probably right. My date is its own executable, but /bin/sed -> busybox

Given the limitations the methods discussed above may not work since you're working with a limited set of features with these tools.

Comment: Quotation marks are not working for me for some reason. `sh` expands the date format as `'+"%Y/%m' '%b/%d"'`.
Also, for some reason `$()` is not working and `sh` tries to execute `=date`, which does not exist.
Here's the output I get when I try your suggested code:
`+++ sed -r -e 's:([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}).*:date -d \1-\2-\3 +"%Y/%m %b/%d":'`
`++ =date -d 2013-10-27 '+"%Y/%m' '%b/%d"'`
`./dvrsnapshots.sh: line 25: =date: command not found`
`+`

Comment: @Serge - I had a typo with the setting of the variable. Please retry. Also are you using sh or bash? You tagged the Q as bash.

Comment: I simplified `MOVEDIRSTR` to:
    MOVEDIR=$(`sed -r -e 's:([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}).*:date -d \1-\2-\3 +"%Y/%m_%b/%d":' <<< "$line"`)
It was necessary to keep tildas inside $(). Still no luck with date formatting though.

Comment: I'm running `/bin/sh` on a QNAP device.

Comment: @Serge - you're likely using a watered down version of these commands provided by BusyBox. If you look at the date command like so: `ls -l /bin/date` it's probably a link to an executable called busybox or something similar. These commands aren't full-featured, hence your problems.

Comment: You're probably right. My `date` is its own executable, but `/bin/sed -> busybox`.

Comment: @Serge - yes so that's why the options aren't working.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would use a glob to avoid [parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and obtaining the list of `.jpg` files in that roundabout way. Second, you can use the shell itself (no need for `sed`) to extract the date components:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in "$IMGDIR"/*.jpg; do
    file_name="$(basename file)"
    printf "%s\n" "$file_name"
    numbers="${file%-*}"
    year="${numbers%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}"
    monthday="${numbers#[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}"
    month="${monthday%[0-9][0-9]}"
    day="${monthday#[0-9][0-9]}"
    movedir="$(date -d "$year-$month-$day" +"%Y/%m %b/)"
    movefile="$(date -d "$year-$month-$day" +"%Y/%m %b/%d)"
    [ -d "$ARCHIVEDIR/$movedir" ] || mkdir -p "$ARCHIVEDIR/$movedir"
    mv "$file" "$movefile"
done
```

This assumes of course that your `date` command has a full enough feature set, since you mentioned it is a separate executable from BusyBox. It will also break if your date string is not exactly 8 digits long.

Answer (score 1):

see if the following could solve the date extraction and formatting part:

```
$ f=20130131-abcdefgh.jpg
$ [[ $f =~ ^([[:digit:]]{4})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2}) ]]
$ yyyy=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
$ mm=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
$ dd=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
$ date -d ${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd} +'%Y/%m %b/%d'
2013/01 Jan/31
```