# Show tail of files in a directory?

Tags: command-line, directory, tail

I have a directory that is too huge to browse by any means. Grepping returns argument lists too long, WINSCP crashes when trying to open the directory.

Is there a way I can view just the last 200 files in the directory. Like 'tailing' the directory?

Comment: It would be as easy as  `ls -l /path/to/dir | tail -n200`

Comment: @val0x00ff "Why one shouldn't parse the output of ls (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) explains why this wouldn't be the best idea

Comment: @chirp in scripts you should not use `ls` indeed. In this case you can because the target is the human eye not the system.

Comment: @val0x00ff yes-*ish*, if you could show me where this is/was defined in the original posting

Comment: @chirp  `ls` is perfectly fine for listing files and directories in combination with other flags. It is however not suited to be used in scripts because it's purpose is to make a human-readable listing. Also the OP doesn't mention it needs a script. That is the reason I used `ls`

Comment: Guys, `ls` is fine to use. I know ppl make a big deal of it on this site, and it can be problematic to parse it, but it's a perfectly fine tool to use and `grep` the output from. The warnings from that wiki are things that you should appreciate about "potential" problems you might run into when parsing it.

Comment: Can you explain the nature of the files in this directory? I find it odd that such a trivially simple Q has had no answers, other than yours that you deleted. This tells me that your Q is poorly being asked. A simple `ls -l | tail -n 200` will do what you want.

Comment: Is there a remote file-browser that can handle huge directories?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Barring your files don't include strange characters in their names, such as spaces, new lines, etc. A simple pipe to `tail -n 200` should suffice.

#### Example

Sample data.

```
$ touch $(seq 300)
```

Now the last 200:

```
$ ls -l | tail -n 200
```

You might not like the way the results are presented in that list of 200. For that you can control the order of the results that `ls` outputs through a variety of switches. For example, the data I've generated is numeric. Using the above method the results are shown like so:

```
$ ls -l | tail -n 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Nov 28 11:50 89
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Nov 28 11:50 9
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Nov 28 11:50 90
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Nov 28 11:50 91
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Nov 28 11:50 92
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Nov 28 11:50 93
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Nov 28 11:50 94
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Nov 28 11:50 95
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Nov 28 11:50 96
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Nov 28 11:50 97
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Nov 28 11:50 98
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Nov 28 11:50 99
```

But maybe you want this in true numeric order, so you could use the `-v` switch:

```
$ ls -lv | tail -n 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Nov 28 11:50 289
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Nov 28 11:50 290
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Nov 28 11:50 291
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Nov 28 11:50 292
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Nov 28 11:50 293
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Nov 28 11:50 294
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Nov 28 11:50 295
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Nov 28 11:50 296
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Nov 28 11:50 297
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Nov 28 11:50 298
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Nov 28 11:50 299
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Nov 28 11:50 300
```

You have to pay special attention to `ls` implementations, since some may include one switch while another may not. Consult the man pages on the respective systems to get the full list of available switches.

Answer (score 1):

In zsh:

```
print -lr -- *([1,200])          # print the name of the first 200 files in alphabetical order
print -lr -- *(om[1,200])        # print the name of the 200 most recent files
print -lr -- *(oN[1,200])        # print the name of 200 files
```

The `oN` variant reads files in directory order, so it doesn't waste time sorting them.

If you want to peek at the file contents as well:

```
tail *(oN[1,200])
```

With any shell, to print the names of 200 files without reading all the file names and sorting them:

```
ls -lU | head -n 200
```

To print the names of the 200 most recent files:

```
ls -lt | head -n 200
```

If you want to move the files into a bunch of directories, see [Batch copy to multiple directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40268/batch-copy-to-multiple-directories), [How can I find files and then use xargs to move them?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90886/how-can-i-find-files-and-then-use-xargs-to-move-them), [Batch copying/moving files in unix?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38038/batch-copying-moving-files-in-unix), [Batch file move to directory structure based on filename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97767/batch-file-move-to-directory-structure-based-on-filename)